# Who says women dying their hands with henna is (im)permissible?

Tags: women, adornments

From Wikipedia:

> The name henna also refers to the dye prepared from the plant and the temporary body art (staining) based on those dyes (see also [mehndi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi)).  -- [Henna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henna), Wikipedia
>
> Mehndi... is a form of body art from Ancient India, in which decorative designs are created on a person's body... -- [Mehndi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi), Wikipedia

[image: Image source: Wikimedia Commons (public domain)]

Some online fatawa say it's recommended:

- Mufti Yaseen Shaikh ([MuftiSays](http://www.muftisays.com/qa/question/362/the-use-of-henna.html)): "It is recommended for women to apply Henna" giving the reason "In view of the above quoted hadith one of the reasons for females applying mehndi is to distinguish her hands from that of a male."

Some online fatawa say it's permissible:

- Qibla.com (sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/36525)): "Yes, a woman can wear hennah, and her wudu will be valid."
- Mufti Ebrahim Desai, [Askimam.org](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/19670): "It is permissible for women to use black henna on their hands and feet."
- [Zikr](http://www.zikr.co.uk/content/view/71/112/): "The Shariah (Islamic law) allows women to use henna."

While others say it is haram or makruh:

- Qibla.com (sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33529)): "It seems that a non-married woman wearing henna is not a sunna and it is either makruh or haram. Or so says Anwar Al-Masalik."
- Abu Yahya, Qibla.com (sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33907)): "Yes, it is offensive (makrooh) for an unmarried woman to wear henna on her hands or feet."

**Question**: Who says women dying their hands with henna is (im)permissible?

Since there's inconsistent scholarly opinion, I'm seeking an overview of the different scholarly thoughts regarding the permissibility of henna depending on sect/school of thought.  (...if possible, if not an answer explaining why this is impossible [or prohibitively difficult] would be fine).

Answer (score 1):

### Shia's view

It seems that Shia consider using Henna as a permissible and even a Mustahab (recommended) practice, although can be Makruh/haram in some exceptions (conditions). But, why does Shia consider it permissible/Mustahab, might be related to its profits, such as:

- Eliminating diseases
- Decreasing of Satan temptation
- Making good-smell
- Cause of happiness
- Protecting adornment
- Social freshness/joy
- Having its Okhrawi (heavenly -future-) profits

And so on.

---

Source:

[www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A8#foot-main25)

[lib.eshia.ir](http://lib.eshia.ir/11025/2/97/%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%A9)

Comment: Is there no shia who says it is impermissible? *btw, maybe you want to answer my question [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40694/15201).*

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if there is (since I didn't search ...), but about your question "praying of women by hijab, when she is alone", Shia also says she must be with hijab.